# How to populate dataTable in Correct Order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am trying to poulate `dataTable` with my Server Side Values but its not getting populated correctly.I am Posting my dataTable Structure code..

```
dt = $("#up").dataTable({
"data": dataSet,
"paging": false,
"responsive": true,
"stateSave": true,
"columns": [
{ "title": "<input type='checkbox' id='selectAll'>", "bSortable": false, "width": "5px", },
{ "title": "", "bSortable": false, "width": "5px" },
{ "title": "Code", "width": "50px" },
{ "title": "Name" },
{ "title": "Contact Name" },
{ "title": "Contact Email" }
]
});
```

In the above Table , i want first column as `Select All` checkbox type and second column as edit column with `edit(Pencil)` icon and rest of the columns with my Server Side Values but currently the data from server side is getting displayed right from first column keeping last two columns empty ..Also i am getting this alert as Warning `DataTables warning: table id=CompanySetup - Requested unknown parameter '4' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4`
Please help me to get it ..Thanks..

Update..

```
@{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(row in model.MyTable)
{
 sb.AppendFormat("['{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}'],",
    row.Field1, row.Field2, row.Field3, row.Field4);
}
}

var dataSet = [@Html.Raw(sb.ToString())];
```

Comment: check this one for more reference

Comment: Show what your server returns. Where are going to add `edit` icons?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Okay My Server Data is coming as Array ..`Array[4]
0: "73878"
1: "Systems"
2: "xyz"
3: "systems.com"
length: 4`

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Any Suggestions to get it done !!

Comment: @Lara You can use `data` in column model, in order to specify the data source. However, you will have to return **objects** instead of **arrays**. Read about it in DataTable documentation.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I have updated my Post with the Data that i am getting from Server Side in my Razor View page..Please have a look and tell me what i need to update in my Current Code ..Thanks

Comment: @Lara You need to stop generating JSON manually. Read carefully about **JSON**, **JSON serialization** in C#. Then, you can serialize your objects to JSON but to an array. Also, it would be good if you didn't inject your JSON into your view directly, but use actions. I am sorry, but this question seems to be really too broad. I really hope that you will get this to work. Hopefully, I will try to answer this question tomorrow, if I have enough time for it.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Actually I am not using MVC in my Project ..Could you please tell me the way i am getting the data in the way , for this how to populate it from 3rd column of my given datatable ..Thats all i wanted as of now..Thanks